# Cannot launch app minimized with /minimized

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, task-scheduler, command-line-arguments

For whatever reason, AMD Gaming Evolved (Raptr) is dying randomly (ticket has been submitted). I made a task schedule that automatically launches Raptr every hour with this action:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Raptr\raptr.exe" /minimized`

Suffice it to say, it's not working. Every hour I see the control panel for Raptr up on my screen most assuredly *not* minimized.

I also tried making a shortcut to ratpr.exe with the `Run` parameter set to `Minimized` to no avail.

I need it to either launch minimized or to the tray if that is possible. Closing the app sends it to the tray which is it's ideal place - I just want it running and out of the way.

Answer (score 4):

Command-line switches are parsed by the application, and there's no guarantee that a given program will know about or respect `/minimized`. Fortunately, there is a way to start programs minimized: with `cmd`'s `start` command.

Change your scheduled task to run `cmd` with the following parameters:

```
/s /c start "" /min "C:\Program Files (x86)\Raptr\raptr.exe"
```

The `""` as the first parameter to `start` prevents the program path from being treated as a window caption. There will be a split-second flash of a command prompt, but it will launch the program and then go away.

Comment: Unfortunately Raptr (AMD Gaming Evolved) is still restored/opened to the front.

Comment: @Enigma It must be doing something special, then. What happens if you get [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and run `nircmd win min stitle` followed by the first word or so of the window caption in quotes?